# How to update an object inside an array inside an object with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

Let's say I want to update "numberOfUpVotes" where the title is "Een centrale plek voor alle ideeen". I want the new value of "numberOfUpVotes" to be stored in the database. How do I do that?

Right now my code doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't work. This is what I've tried:

```
 Board.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"ideas.numberOfUpVotes": 23},
        {$set: {"numberOfUpVotes": 2}}, // $set
        {new: true},
        function (err, doc) {
            if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
            console.log("hallo");
        });
```

This is my data:

```
{
collectionName: "Board",
boardName: "IdeaBoard Schiphol",
ideas: [
    {
    _id: ida1,
    userId: id1,
    title: 'Een centrale plek voor alle ideeen',
    text: 'Een plek waar alle ideeen getoond worden op een scherm ofzo. Waar mensen dan op kunnnen stemmen via hun telefoon',
    date: new Date('2019-04-12'),
    numberOfUpVotes: 23,
    },
    {
    _id: ida2,
    userId: id1,
    title: 'Een uber voor kerstbomen',
    text: 'Bestaat zoiets al?',
    date: new Date('2019-04-11'),
    numberOfUpVotes: 1,
    }
],
QRcode: 'Dit is een QRcode'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final answer:

```
Board.update(
    {"ideas._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("abc123")},
    {$inc:{"ideas.$.numberOfUpVotes": 1}},
    function (err, doc) {
        if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
        console.log("succes! (:");
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without mongoose, something like.

```js
const board = {
  collectionName: "Board",
  boardName: "IdeaBoard Schiphol",
  ideas: [
      {
      _id: 'ida1 (demo)',
      userId: 'id1 (demo)',
      title: 'Een centrale plek voor alle ideeen',
      text: 'Verkort voor demonstratie',
      date: new Date('2019-04-12'),
      numberOfUpVotes: 23,
      },
      {
      _id: 'ida2 (demo)',
      userId: 'id1 (demo)',
      title: 'Een uber voor kerstbomen',
      text: 'Bestaat zoiets al?',
      date: new Date('2019-04-11'),
      numberOfUpVotes: 1,
      }
  ],
  QRcode: 'Dit is een QRcode'
};

// find the filtered record and update its value
// the found record is a reference, so the value 
// is indeed changed within the object
board.ideas.filter(idea => idea.numberOfUpVotes === 23).shift().numberOfUpVotes = 2;

// QED
console.log(JSON.stringify(board, null, " "));
```

Comment: This works only for the object that is returned. I would like to edit the database object as well.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm not well versed in mongoose, but isn't it possible to use a filter function (like in the answer) as first argument? Or maybe `Board.findOneAndUpdate([{"ideas.numberOfUpVotes": 23}], ...)`?